# Current best methods for solving dynamic optimization problems in high dimensional state spaces

Tags: dynamic-programming, dynamic-optimization, optimal-control, recursive-macroeconomics

I was wondering what the current best methods are for solving dynamic optimization problems in high dimensional state spaces. Let me lay out the common cases where I would do something like this in economics. Say I am trying to solve either a finite or infinite time horizon optimization problem, such as expected utility maximization. Further, I can look at either discrete time or continuous time models.

So say I have a large state vector, on the order of 100-1000 elements. Using dynamic programming methods will not work in such high dimensional state spaces. I was trying to understand what methods could work on these scales.

In looking at the chapter 7 of *Handbook of Computational Economics* by Judd, et al., they mention a few methods including Smolyak's method, Monte Carlo methods, among other choices, but that book was written in 2014, so it is getting a bit dated vis-a-vis recent developments.

One promising area seems to be direct collocation methods, which can solve nonlinear control problems in high dimension, but I am not sure if these methods have been implemented in Economics thus far.

So I was trying to get a sense of what approaches seem promising--taking advantage of GPUs and parallel processing potentially--so that I can start to look around in the literature. Any suggestions would be appreciated.